# beautiful soup not to parse nested table data

Tags: python-3.x, html-table, beautifulsoup

I have a nested table structure. I am using the below code for parsing the data.

```
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:][:-1]:
    for td in row.find_all("td")[1:]:
        dataset = td.get_text()
```

The problem here is when there are nested tables like in my case there are tables inside `<td></td>` so these are parsed again after parsing initially as I am using `find_all(tr)` and `find_all(td)`. So how can I avoid parsing the nested table as it is parsed already?

**Input:**

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td>1</td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>3</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>5 
    <table><tr><td>11</td><td>22</td></tr></table>
      6
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1  2
3  4
5  
11 22
6
```

**But what I am getting is:**

```
1 2
3 4
5
11 22
11 22
6
```

That is, the inner table is parsed again.

**Specs:**
beautifulsoup4==4.6.3

Data order should be preserved and content could be anything including any alphanumeric characters.

Comment: is there an url to share and can you indicate expected output?

Comment: if your `td` are direct children of your rows, you can use `recursive=False` as argument in the `find_all` method. Like: `row.find_all("td", recursive=False)`

Comment: @Maaz tried it but still it parses

Comment: If you can give some concrete examples of input and your desired results it would be better.

Comment: @InfectedDrake, I had added sample input and expected output

Answer (score 2):

Using a combinations of bs4 and re, you might achieve what you want.

I am using bs4 4.6.3

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

html = '''
<table>
<tr>
   <td>1</td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>3</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>5 
    <table><tr><td>11</td><td>22</td></tr></table>
      6
  </td>
</tr>
</table>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

ans = []

for x in soup.findAll('td'):
    if x.findAll('td'):
        for y in re.split('<table>.*</table>', str(x)):
            ans += re.findall('\d+', y)
    else:
        ans.append(x.text)
print(ans)
```

For each `td` we test if this is a nest `td`. If so, we split on table and take everything and match with a regex every number.

Note this working only for two depths level, but adaptable to any depths

Comment: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '11', '22'] output is fine but order is gone! This is what is expected ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '11', '22','6']

Comment: content could be anything, not just number

Comment: Thanks for pointing out :) you should add these specifications un your question

Comment: I was trying to give a minimal example so couldn't cover all aspects

Comment: And you are right ! But now this is part of the specifications, and this should now be in the question :)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried with findChilden() method and some how managed to produce output.I am not sure if this will help you in any other circumstances.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='''<table>
<tr>
   <td>1</td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>3</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>5 
    <table><tr><td>11</td><td>22</td></tr></table>
      6
  </td>
</tr>
</table>'''


soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

for child in soup.find('table').findChildren("tr" , recursive=False):
  tdlist = []
  if child.find('table'):
     for td in child.findChildren("td", recursive=False):
         print(td.next_element.strip())
         for td1 in td.findChildren("table", recursive=False):
             for child1 in td1.findChildren("tr", recursive=False):
                 for child2 in child1.findChildren("td", recursive=False):
                     tdlist.append(child2.text)
                 print(' '.join(tdlist))
                 print(child2.next_element.next_element.strip())
  else:

     for td in child.findChildren("td" , recursive=False):
         tdlist.append(td.text)
     print(' '.join(tdlist))
```

### Output:

```
1 2
3 4
5
11 22
6
```

---

### EDITED for Explanation

**Step 1:**

When use `findChilden()` inside table it first returns 3 records.

```
for child in soup.find('table').findChildren("tr", recursive=False):
    print(child)
```

### Output:

```
<tr>
<td>1</td><td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td><td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5 
        <table><tr><td>11</td><td>22</td></tr></table>
          6
      </td>
</tr>
```

---

**Step 2:**

Check that any children has tag `<table>` and do some operation.

```
 if child.find('table'):
```

---

**Step 3:**

Follow the step 1 and use `findChilden()` to get `<td>` tag.

Once you get the `<td>` follow step 1 to get the children again.

---

**Step 4:**

```
for td in child.findChildren("td", recursive=False)            
      print(td.next_element.strip())
```

Next element will return the first text of tag so in that case it will return the value 5.

---

**Step 5**

```
for td in child.findChildren("td", recursive=False):
             print(td.next_element.strip())
             for td1 in td.findChildren("table", recursive=False):
                 for child1 in td1.findChildren("tr", recursive=False):
                     for child2 in child1.findChildren("td", recursive=False):
                         tdlist.append(child2.text)
                     print(' '.join(tdlist))
                     print(child2.next_element.next_element.strip())
```

If you see here i have just follows step 1 recursively.Yes Again I have used `child2.next_element.next_element` to get the value of 6 after `</table>` tag.

Comment: can you explain the code so that I can understand and use it according to my requirements

Comment: @Nagaraju : are you happy with the explanation or you need further help on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if another `table` exists inside a `td` tag, if it exists then simply skip that `td`, otherwise use it as a regular `td`.

```py
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:][:-1]:
    for td in row.find_all("td")[1:]:
        if td.find('table'):  # check if td has nested table
            continue
        dataset = td.get_text()
```

Comment: This works but it skips any text in that <td> that is outside the nested table

Answer (score 0):

In your example, with bs4 4.7.1 I use :has :not to exclude looping rows with table child

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
for tr in soup.select('tr:not(:has(table))'):
    print([td.text for td in tr.select('td')])
```

Comment: I am using beautifulsoup4==4.6.3

Comment: I would suggest upgrading given 4.7.1 is both more reliable and has more functionality.